# Text clustering/NLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-classification

Imagine there is a column in dataset representing university. We need to classify the values, i.e. number of groups after classification should be as equal as possible to real number of universities. The problem is that there might be different naming for the same university. An example: University of Stanford = Stanford University = Uni of Stanford. Is there any certain NLP method/function/solution in Python 3?

Let's consider both cases: data might be tagged as well as untagged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Speaking of Stanford, have you heard of the CoreNLP library? Tried it?

Comment: I will try it, haven't heard of it. Thanks for the sharing.

Comment: HI, I am on elasticserach, not python so it is kinda different.. I goy yo spend lots of time to find a solution... please find my problem in the comment below.

Comment: Sure, your data is stored there. That doesn't mean you can't query for something, then use Python libraries to do something else to the data, then insert results back to Elastic

Comment: @cricket_007 thats an option. I'm curious how that would behave if i have 5 milion unique names from elastic and want to match them with original list of 5 thousand unviverisites names. My first idea is to try matching using n-grams (probably trigrams vs. bigrams + stemmed vs. not stemmed). What are your thoughts?

Comment: Not clear how names match to universities or why ngrams are needed, but since I come from a Hadoop background, I would use Pyspark and the above CoreNLP library to scale out the processing

Answer (score 2):

A very simple unsupervised approach would be to use a k-means based approach. The advantage here is that you know exactly how many clusters (k) you  expect, since you know the number of universities in advance.

Then you could use a package such as [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) to create your feature vectors (most likely n-grams of characters using a [Countvectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) with the option analyzer=char) and you can use the clustering to group together similarly written universities.

There is no guarantee that the groups will match perfectly, but I think that it should work quite well, as long as the different spellings are somewhat similar.

Comment: @BC1554 Any update on whether this approach was useful?

Comment: Hi I thought I will use Python in my new job..However... I am using ElasticSearch so it is kind of different. I am trying to implement match_phrase + fuzziness but it seems like it is impossible (not that much examples online, no such cases in the documentation describer)... Anyboday has experience on phrase matching including fuzziness on ElasticSearch? Thanks in advance :)